# If $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $|x_1+x_2| = |x_1| + |x_2|$, prove that $x_1 x_2 \geq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $|x_1+x_2| = |x_1| + |x_2|$, prove that $x_1 x_2 \geq 0$.

My attempt:

$$|x_1+x_2| = |x_1| + |x_2|$$

$$|x_1+x_2|^2 = (|x_1| + |x_2|)^2$$

$$ x_1^2+2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = x_1^2+|2x_1x_2| + x_2^2 $$

Therefore, $x_1x_2 = |x_1x_2|$ $\iff x_1x_2 \geq 0$

Is this a valid approach to doing this proof? Any critiques or comments to improve would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $x_1x_2 \geq 0$ implies that they share signs. What if $x_1, x_2 \leq 0$?

Comment: @David That happens because the statement to prove is, in fact, wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question is to show that $x_1x_2\geq 0$, then your proof is perfectly fine. (If it is, as in your title, to show that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $\geq 0$, then the claim is of course false.) If you wanted to improve it, you could add in something explaining how you go from $|x_1+x_2|^2$ to $x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2$, since that step involves two deductions, but what you have is certainly fine. In general, adding more explanatory words instead of just calculations is good.

Another way you could do it is to split into cases based on the signs of $x_1$ and $x_2$, which is conceptually simpler but probably involves a longer write-up.